# Can only one loop be used to calculate percentage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a requirement to find sum of an attribute of each JSON row and then add another attribute to show percentage of corresponding attribute.
The JSON is as follows -

```
[
    {"value":150, ...},
    {"value":125, ...},
    {"value":100, ...},
    {"value":60, ...},
    {"value":30, ...}
]
```

Now, I've written following code.

```
var totalVal = 0;
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
    totalVal += value.value;
});
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
    value.label = Math.round((value.value / totalVal) * 10000) / 100 + "%";
});
```

I've to use 2 loops to achieve the result. Is there any way to do this in single loop?

EDIT: The code I've written works perfectly. Since I'm contributing back to publicly available GitHub project, I really want to know if the method is most efficient.

Comment: Since you need totalValue to compute the label, it seems like it might be hard to stick one loops.

Comment: I don't think it is possible.. because first you need to find the total then the percentage

Comment: No. The result will be all wrong.
See in loop execution totalValue will vary as 150, 275, ... So your percentage vary as 100%, 45.45%, ...

Comment: @Bart care to explain more?

Comment: create a jsfiddle for that..

Comment: @ahren I had no idea what codereview is. I do think this question should go there. Can I move this question, or should I ask there again?

Comment: @BikasVaibhav - Yeah it's a new stackexchange site still in beta. I'll flag the question and see if one of the mod's will move it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `totatVal` won't be a `totalVal` until you loop through all the rows to find it.
It might be solved by a single loop with some fancy standard functions but at the end it will come down to 2 loops.

It's pure math - you need to count your total value first in order to find a correct % of each of your values.